# MongoDB schema design for document that can be embedded or stand alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I am relatively new to MongoDB and am still getting used to schema design.

In a project that I am currently working on, users can tag files that they upload. There are three types of tags: descriptive, brand, and store_department. They are presented as three fields to the user but in reality they are merged together and saved as tags, i.e.:

```
"tags" : [
  {
    "type" : "descriptive",
    "tag" : "this is my tag"
  },
  {
    "type" : "brand",
    "tag" : "this is another tag"
  }
]
```

This is to make searching very easy. By using a type, I can present the user three distinct fields to encourage them to provide the information as well as then allow for more advanced queries such as search by brand or store department. A default search will just search for matching tags.

The issue is that I provide autocomplete functionality in all of the fields. As the user types in the "brand" field, all created tags of type "brand" are displayed that match their input. This is easily accomplished by having a stand alone tag collection. New tag documents are created and updated when the file document is saved. The autocomplete queries against the stand alone tag collection instead of the embedded tags for performance.

Something feels wrong with this design. It is a duplication of efforts in some regard but seems to work great as far as the user experience is concerned. I use Mongoid and to accomodate this design have had to create two models for my tag collections. One that defines the two attributes and a second that inherits from the first but adds the embedded_in macro.

I could see this pattern being useful in other instances as well: products and shopping carts, products and purchase orders, etc. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something feels wrong with this design. It is a duplication of efforts in some regard but seems to work great as far as the user experience is concerned.

In a NoSQL database, you have to denormalize sometimes. This will lead to some amount of data duplication. But as it can greatly improve performance (and works great for user experience), this should be worth it.

So a collection with distinct tag name to be used for autocompletion might make sense. It will be much smaller than the non-distinct tags in the embedded documents. Nothing wrong with that approach.

This "master" collection would be a good place to add additional meta-data for the tag, for example the description and wiki Stackoverflow has for tags here.

Also, it might be better to have a separate field for every type of tag if there are only a few types. This way, you can index them separately.

```
"tags" : { "descriptive: [ "this is my tag" ],
           "brand": ["this is another tag" ] }
```